# why am i getting Python Module error for OmegaExpansion header. Can anyone help me?

Tags: python, ocpp

`from OmegaExpansion import onionI2C`

I am not able to install OmegaExpansion.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OmegaExpansion'`

Comment: That module is provided by a third party; you will have to install it yourself.  Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be you have not configured your feeds correctly. Look at /etc/opkg/distfeeds.conf

Uncomment each of the lines then run opkg update.

Then take a look at http://repo.onioniot.com/omega2/packages/packages/

Some examples of how to install python packages based upon what you see in the above repo:

````
opkg install python-pip-conf
opkg install python-pip```
````